# computing the difference of two rows with respect two other conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wondering how could I be doing the following in SQL for my dataset as shown below. For each row:

1. With respect to MachCode and WorkType (i.e. order by these two)
2. I want to compute diam change from one date (and time) to other, in a new column. Fill with zero, if no difference.
3. Similarly for the thickness and slope. (in new columns)

Data:

```
MachCode    WorkType    Date    Time    Diam    Thickness   Slope

XHPUS0001   Lathing 07MAY07 0:00    873.30000   .   .
XHPUS0001   Lathing 13DEC07 9:55    863.80000   .   .
XHPUS0001   Lathing 05FEB10 8:40    863.80000   .   .
XHPUS0001   Lathing 03APR12 14:32   890.60000   32.5000 11.0000
XHPUS0001   Facing  02JAN13 19:24   876.00000   .   .
XHPUS0001   Lathing 12JAN15 7:00    .   .   .
XHPUS0002   Lathing 07MAY07 0:00    890.90000   .   .
XHPUS0002   Lathing 07SEP09 7:26    890.90000   32.5000 .
XHPUS0002   Facing  29NOV10 12:15   884.45000   32.5000 .
XHPUS0002   Lathing 10SEP11 20:46   878.85000   .   .
XHPUS0002   Lathing 04FEB12 21:49   874.10000   30.0000 loka.00
XHPUS0003   Lathing 19SEP07 0:00    879.90000   .   .
XHPUS0003   Lathing 23.marras.09    15:49   870.80000   .   .
XHPUS0003   Lathing 4.marras.10 15:15   870.80000   .   .
XHPUS0003   Lathing 06NOV10 13:24   864.10000   .   .
XHPUS0003   Facing  27APR11 10:13   852.30000   .   .
XHPUS0003   Lathing 17SEP11 19:31   847.00000   .   .
XHPUS000323 Lathing 17FEB09 0:00    868.05000   .   .
XHPUS000323 Lathing 22NOV09 12:50   868.05000   31.5100 loka.00
XHPUS000323 Lathing 06SEP10 13:35   857.80000   31.5100 loka.00
XHPUS000323 Lathing 02NOV10 15:00   890.80000   28.0000 .
XHPUS000323 Lathing 26SEP11 11:11   879.70000   .   .
XHPUS000323 Lathing 29DEC11 13:04   859.50000   30.5000 .
XHPUS000323 Lathing 28JAN12 8:53    857.60000   .   .
XHPUS000323 Lathing 28JAN12 11:58   857.60000   .   .
XHPUS000323 Lathing 13OCT12 19:37   852.15000   .   .
XHPUS000323 Lathing 31OCT12 14:03   890.50000   32.5000 11.0000
XHPUS000323 Facing  16.marras.13    19:52   888.70000   .   .
XHPUS000323 Lathing 12OCT13 13:49   886.70000   30.8000 loka.00
XHPUS000323 Lathing 12OCT13 14:17   886.70000   30.8000 loka.00
```

I tried with select code

```
select * from T1 order by MachCode, WorkType, Date, Time;
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: is that date field a text field?  Is date/time 2 separate fields?

Comment: @AndrewDeighton No this is date type ddMMMyy (one of the many formats). and yes Date and Time are two different columns.

Answer (score 0):

OUTER APPLY TO the TOP 1 of the same type, where the date is earlier in time and we are ordering by date descending

```
select T1.*,  
       COALESCE(T1.Diam - DQ.Diam , 0) DiamDelta, 
       COALESCE(T1.thickness - DQ.thickness,0) ThicknessDelta,
       COALESCE(T1.slope - DQ.slope,0) SlopeDelta from T1 

        OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 T1A.diam, T1A.thickness,T1A.slope FROM T1 T1A 
                    WHERE T1A.MachCode = T1.MachCode 
                            AND T1A.WorkType     = T1.WorkType     
                            AND (T1A.DATE < T1.Date OR T1A.DATE = T1.Date AND T1A.Time < T1.Time)
                    ORDER BY T1A.Date DESC , T1A.time DESC) DQ
    order by T1.MachCode, T1.WorkType, T1.[Date], T1.[Time];
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. let me check it.

Comment: select T1.*
19                COALESCE(T1.DiameterAfterFacing - DQ.DiameterAfterFacing , 0) DiamDelta,
                  ________
                  22
                  76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, *, **, +, ',', -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, BETWEEN, 
              CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, GE, GET, GT, GTT, LE, LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, OR, ^=, |, ||, ~=.  

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Comment: @MANU - is this Microsoft SQL Server?  Or is it another SQL version, SAS possibly?

Comment: SAS Andrew. it is SAS